# how to combine 60 matrices in R quickly

Tags: r, matrix

I have 60 matrices in R named as mat1, mat2....mat60 and I would like to combine them into a big matrix using rbind. I know that I could write something like

```
matList <- list(mat1, mat2, ... mat60)
rbind(matList)
```

but it seems a very dumb solution. Any idea how I can simplify the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this question *really* relates to the OP having to type out the names of the matrices manually. You can use `mget` to return the matrices in a list and then use `do.call` and `rbind` as posed by @Michele like this (assuming the matrices are located in the `.GlobalEnv` ):

```
matList <- mget(paste0("mat",1:60),env=globalenv())
bigm <- do.call("rbind" , matList)
```

Comment: yes! you probably right! the OP mainly needs `mget`. He definitely does not mention any list. He just typed `list(mat1, mat2, .., mat60)`

Comment: @Michele great answer with all the timings. +1 to you.

Answer (score 13):

I supposed they all have same number of column (and same `colnames`). If so, try this:

```
do.call("rbind", matlist)
```

otherwise:

```
matlist <- lapply(matlist, as.data.frame)

library(plyr)
rbind.fill(matlist)
```

EDIT:

adding some timings:

```
lst <- list()

for(i in 1:1000)
  lst[[i]] <- matrix(rnorm(10000, 100))

f1 <- function()
  do.call("rbind", lst)

f2 <- function(){
  lst <- lapply(lst, as.data.table)
  rbindlist(lst)
}

library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

> microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
Unit: milliseconds
 expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
 f1()  53.78661  55.22728  63.43546  66.08829 103.1996   100
 f2() 210.46232 215.32043 217.93846 221.35012 333.2758   100
```

If the OP has got his data in matrices I thought that including `lst <- lapply(lst, as.data.table)` was the correct way of comparison. Otherwise it would be:

```
> lst.dt <- lapply(lst, as.data.table)
> f2 <- function(){
+   rbindlist(lst.dt)
+ }
> microbenchmark(f1(), f2())
Unit: milliseconds
 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
 f1() 49.00308 50.28515 54.98947 60.71945 87.66487   100
 f2() 24.23454 28.57692 31.79278 32.75494 63.78825   100
```

Comment: do note that in case of matrices colnames don't matter in the `do.call(rbind` - the rbind will not care if the names are different; it will only complain if those are data.frames (it might not do what you want, but it will not complain)

Comment: I know (...) first columns with first columns, second with second and forth. and the `colnames` will be taken from the first matrix. but it wouldn't be meaningful...

Comment: @Michele Might I suggest that you add @JackManey proposition with just a `for` loop in your benchmark... +1 for  benchmark effort of course.

Comment: @agstudy do you mean the 1st with the 2nd, the result with the third, then with the 4th and so on? :-D this is gonna be interesting... :-))) one sec

Comment: another benchmark suggestion - convert to `data.frame`: `lst.df = lapply(lst, as.data.frame)`, and try the `do.call(rbind,` approach on that (this is to illustrate that having a `data.table` **really** matters)

Comment: @eddi in the second `microbenchmark` I left the argument of `do.call` a list of matrix on purpose, 'cause `rbind` is much slower in more complex structure (i.e. df and dt). it was 300ms against 54ms

Comment: @agstudy @eddi Ladies and Gentlemen we have the winner... the `for` loop took 29 sec. Sorry I really  can't post that... :-)

Answer (score 6):

This should be faster:

```
 library(data.table)
 rbindlist(matList)
```

**EDIT**
  The above solution will work for list of data.frame or list, If you have a list of matrix you should convert them before:

```
 rbindlist(lapply(ll,as.data.frame))
```

Comment: It's not implemented (yet?) for matrices: *"Item 1 of list input is not a data.frame, data.table or list"*

Comment: it is indeed!. it would be great if `rbindlist` could include the "fill" feature of `rbind.fill`

Comment: @eddi it's prob a matrix (or a generic vector) then. this the second drawback of `rbindlist`

Comment: @agstudy I never said it can. My main answer id `do.call`...regarding perfomance working with `matrix` is in general faster. I use df and dt only if I need join and multi class structures

Comment: @Michele so the logical conclusion is to edit your answer and remove the `rbind.fill` part as it's incorrect (as far as the OP problem goes); or edit it an explain that the `plyr` part is about a different problem

Comment: @eddi the OP doens't provide a reproducible example...and a data.frame  can be assimilated as a matrix...

Comment: @agstudy - I assume you mean the other way around and ok, then assimilate, as is, OP uses the word matrix a few times and without evidence to the contrary, I think that means `matrix`.

Comment: @eddi I already explained before that the `plyr` method was meant only in case the OP has different colnames...