# Adding data frames as list elements (using for loop)

Tags: r, list, for-loop, dataframe

I have in my environment a series of data frames called EOG. There is one for each year between 2006 and 2012. Like, EOG2006, EOG2007...EOG2012. I would like to add them as elements of a list.

First, I am trying to know if this is possible. I read the official R guide and a couple of R programming manuals but I didn't find explicit examples about that.

Second, I would like to do this using a for loop. Unfortunately, the code I used to do the job is wrong and I am going crazy to fix it.

```
for (j in 2006:2012){
z<-j
sEOG<-paste("EOG", z, sep="")
dEOG<-get(paste("EOG", z, sep=""))
lsEOG<-list()
lsEOG[[sEOG]]<-dEOG
}
```

This returns a list with one single element. Where is the mistake?

Comment: `list <- mget( ls( pattern = "^EOG20[0-1][0-9]$" ) )` See e.g. this answer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/17307236/1478381 on `mget` or the [help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html)

Comment: Thank you SimonO101. This solution is probably the most efficient one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You keep reinitializing the list inside the loop.  You need to move `lsEOG<-list()` outside the `for` loop.

```
lsEOG<-list()

for (j in 2006:2012){
  z <- j
  sEOG <- paste("EOG", z, sep="")
  dEOG <- get(paste("EOG", z, sep=""))
  lsEOG[[sEOG]] <-dEOG
}
```

Also, you can use `j` directly in the `paste` functions:

```
sEOG <- paste("EOG", j, sep="")
```

Answer (score 23):

I had the same question, but felt that the OP's initial code was a bit opaque for R beginners.  So, here is perhaps a bit clearer example of how to create data frames in a loop and add them to a list which I just now figured out by playing around in the R shell:

```
 > dfList <- list()  ## create empty list
 >
 > for ( i in 1:5 ) {
 +     x <- rnorm( 4 )
 +     y <- sin( x )
 +     dfList[[i]] <- data.frame( x, y )  ## create and add new data frame
 + }
 >
 > length( dfList )  ## 5 data frames in list
 [1] 5
 >
 > dfList[[1]]    ## print 1st data frame
            x          y
 1 -0.3782376 -0.3692832
 2 -1.3581489 -0.9774756
 3  1.2175467  0.9382535
 4 -0.7544750 -0.6849062
 >
 > dfList[[2]]    ## print 2nd data frame
            x          y
 1 -0.1211670 -0.1208707
 2 -1.5318212 -0.9992406
 3  0.8790863  0.7701564
 4  1.4014124  0.9856888
 >
 > dfList[[2]][4,2]   ## in 2nd data frame, print element in row 4 column 2
 [1] 0.9856888
 >
```

For R beginners like me, note that double brackets are required to access the ith data frame.  Basically, double brackets are used for lists while single brackets are used for vectors.

Answer (score 1):

If the data frames are saved as an object you can find them by `apropos("EOG", ignore.case=FALSE)` and them with a loop store them in the list:

```
list.EOG<- apropos("EOG", ignore.case=FALSE) #Find the objects with case sensitive 
lsEOG<-NULL #Creates the object to full fill in the list
for (j in 1:length(list.EOG)){
lsEOG[i]<-get(list.EOG[i]) #Add the data.frame to each element of the list
}
```

to add the name of each one to the list you can use:

```
names(lsEOG, "names")<-list.EOG
```